# Extending a php file with function inside

Tags: php, laravel

I have a php library named file1.php. And inside this file 1, I have a function name called func1($param1) that accepts 1 parameter. How can I override that function in my file2.php if I wanted to have the same name, func1, but my function is accepting 2 parameters? Like func1($param1, $param2). Note, in file1, it doesn't have any class name like:

```
<?php

function func1($param)
{
  //code
}
```

Thank you for all your help!

I've tried editing artisan and index.php, btw I'm using laravel, and require on load, but it blows up the error of cannot redeclare that function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't override a function that's already defined. What could do for example, is create a second function that proxies the first, and performs some more logic.

For example:

```php
function func1($param)
{
    //code
}


function func2($param, $otherParam)
{
    echo $otherParam; // Do something with your second param

    return func1($param);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Ihope that if other people encounter this scenario, this answer will be helpful to them. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As @atymic already pointed out, what you are describing ([function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading)) is not possible in PHP... without objects and the [__call](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) magic method.  The following is how to accomplish what you asked, except using OOP.

CommonInterface.php

```
<?php

interface CommonInterface
{
    public function __call($name, $arguments);
}
```

ObjectOne.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use BadMethodCallException;

/**
 * @method int func1(string $arg1, array $arg2 = [])
 */
class ObjectOne implements CommonInterface
{
    /**
     * @param $name
     * @param $arguments
     */
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        switch ($name) {
            case "func1":
                $this->myFunc1(...$arguments);

            default:
                throw new BadMethodCallException();
        }
    }

    private function myFunc1($arg1, array $arg2)
    {
        // Do Something

        return 5;
    }
}
```

ObjectTwo.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use BadMethodCallException;

/**
 * @method bool func1(int $arg1)
 */
class ObjectTwo implements CommonInterface
{
    /**
     * @param $name
     * @param $arguments
     */
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        switch ($name) {
            case "func1":
                $this->myFunc1(...$arguments);

            default:
                throw new BadMethodCallException();
        }
    }

    private function myFunc1($arg1)
    {
        // Do Something Else

        return true;
    }
}
```

An alternative to the __call magic method would be to specify no arguments and use the [func_get_args](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.func-get-args.php) function within the method to get the appropriate arguments in each implementation.  This method still requires objects.

ObjectOne.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use BadMethodCallException;

/**
 * @method int func1(string $arg1, array $arg2 = [])
 */
class ObjectOne
{
    public function func1()
    {
        if (func_num_args() != 2) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException();
        }

        $arguments = func_get_args();

        if (!is_string($arguments[0])) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException();
        }

        if (!is_array($arguments[1])) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException();
        }

        // Do Something

        return 5;
    }
}
```

ObjectTwo.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use BadMethodCallException;

/**
 * @method bool func1(int $arg1)
 */
class ObjectTwo extends ObjectOne
{
    public function func1()
    {
        if (func_num_args() != 1) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException();
        }

        $arguments = func_get_args();

        if (!is_int($arguments[0])) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException();
        }

        // Do Something Else

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Ihope that if other people encounter this scenario, this answer will be helpful to them. Thank you!